# Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'asd123' in 'field list' in node js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I receive this error when I'm trying to update table in phpmyadmin

can anyone tell me what's wrong please

this is the table

```
create table ms_registereduser(userID Varchar(10),socketID Varchar(255));
```

this is my server.js

```
var http = require("http");

var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'pushnotificationdb'
});

var userID = "1234567890",
    socketID = "asd123";


http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");

  response.end();
}).listen(1111);

connection.connect();

    connection.query('callpushnotificationdb.spUpdateSocketID('+userID+','+socketID+');').on('end',function()
        {
          console.log('User '+ userID+' has updated his socketID to '+socketID);
        });

connection.end();
```

and this is my spUpdateSocketID with '//' as a delimiter

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spUpdateSocketID//

CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateSocketID(IN userID Varchar(10) ,IN socketID Varchar(255))
BEGIN
set @userID = userID;
set @socketID = socketID;
set @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ms_registereduser SET socketID = @socketID WHERE userID = @userID');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
```

If I try to call the procedure in phpmyadmin like this

```
call pushnotificationdb.spUpdateSocketID('1234567890','asd123');
```

it works, but if I try to call it from node.js it gave me error like this Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'asd123' in 'field list' , please help

Answer (score 4):

Try the below query, the variables `'+userID+'` and `'+socketID+'` are modified as `"'+userID+'"` and `"'+socketID+'"`:

```
connection.query(
  'callpushnotificationdb.spUpdateSocketID("'+userID+'","'+socketID+'");'
)
.on('end',function(){
  console.log('User '+ userID+' has updated his socketID to '+socketID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spUpdateSocketID//

CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateSocketID(IN _userID VARCHAR(10) ,IN _socketID VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
UPDATE ms_registereduser SET socketID = _socketID WHERE userID = _userID;
END//
```

Re-write your procedure as mentioed below and try to run it:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spUpdateSocketID//

CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateSocketID(IN userID VARCHAR(10) ,IN socketID VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @s = CONCAT("UPDATE ms_registereduser SET socketID = '", socketID, "' WHERE userID = '", userID, "'");
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
```

Comment: Update your question with Create table sample data that contain same userId

Comment: I've post the create table syntax used in my code and I've tried your newer code version, still got the same error